# using bash command to remove nextline,space

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

Is sed command capable of removing space,nextline?

I want to have the following output(see output below)

```
TESTING     The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog


TESTING02   The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

TESTING03   The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog


            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog


            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

The output should be the following

```
TESTING     The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

TESTING02   The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

TESTING03   The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Answer (score 4):

If you like to try `awk` you can do:

```
awk '/TESTING/ && NR>1 {print ""} NF' file
TESTING     The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

TESTING02   The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

TESTING03   The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

`NF` prevents it from printing blank line.
`/TESTING/ && NR>1 {print ""}` adds one blank line before `TESTING` line except for first line

Answer (score 3):

for your structure

```
sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d
1!{
   /^TESTING/ s//\
&/
  }' YourFile
```

remove "space line" and ad a new line before `TESTING` entry (but not for 1st line)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\S/!d;1b;/TESTING/i\\' file
```

Delete any empty lines and insert one before a line containing `TESTING` unless it's the first.